# Why are my list objects locations in memory?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert a list of objects into json but the values are the location in memory.

```
public class User {

private String name;
private int score;

public User(String name, int score){
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}

User user1= new User("Luke", 50);
User user2 = new User("Ryan", 70);
List<User> list = Arrays.asList(user1, user2);
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = gson.toJson(list);  
System.out.println(list);
```

The last line is supposed to show my objects in json but instead i just get [User@579bb367, User@1de0aca6], why is this? thanks

Comment: you print the list ?may be `System.out.println(json);`

Comment: Your User class has to define the toString method for the toJson method to work properly.

Comment: `list` is of type `List<User>` , and `User` doesn't have a overridden `toString()`

Comment: "values" are hash codes of `User` instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant

```
System.out.println(json);
```

What you did was to print the List, that, without a toString, will just print a default hash

Answer (score 0):

You just print the hashcode of the list. When you call System.out.println() method, it will call toString() method of List. It is

> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `toString()` method for the Object inside your list, or you will get the hash codes.

Answer (score 0):

When you print a list, you're in fact (implicitly) calling its `toString()` method, which usually just calls each of its element's `toString()`s, concatinates them with commas and encloses them in brackets. If your `User` class does not override `toString()` it will use `Object`'s implementation that just prints the class' simple name and its default `hashCode()`, which is typically the memory address. If you want something more intelligent there, you'd have to override `toString()`. E.g.:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("[User name %s, score %d]", name, score);
}
```